# Django Model ImageField default value

Tags: django

I made a model which has an image field and it is allowed to be blank. How can I have a default image for the model when no image is set for it?

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(blank=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify a [**`default=…`** value [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, default='path/to/image.png')
```

the path is relative to the [**`MEDIA_ROOT`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT).

Answer (score 1):

**Do this:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
        picture = models.ImageField(blank=True,default="Add image url which is you want")
```